# Is willMoveToSuperview called (with nil) when removing a view from a hierarchy?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

If you implement `willMoveToSuperview` on a `UIView` subclass, is it guaranteed to be called (with `nil`) when `removeFromSuperview` is called on your view?

The docs say that the `newSuperview` parameter *may* be `nil` and that it's called *"whenever the superview changes"* but I'm not sure if I can interpret this to mean it will be called when the view is removed from its superview even when not being moved to a different superview.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever a view receives `removeFromSuperview`, and the view's superview was not already nil, the view will always do `[self willMoveToSuperview:nil]`.

Comment: Are you assuming that the view is still retained? If its old super view is the sole owner, the view will be gone forever after `removeFromSuperview`, right?

Comment: The `removeFromSuperview` method sends `willMoveToSuperview:` and `didMoveToSuperview` to `self` before finally releasing `self`.  If the superview had the only strong reference to the subview, the subview will receive the messages before being deallocated.