# how to know if UICollectionViewCell is about to be dequed?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, first-responder

How can I get informed when UICollectionViewCell is about to be scroll out from superview (will be queued)? I need to resignFirstResponder from that cell before the cell is queued.

Comment: Not related to Xcode. As to the question, you could implement the [`willMoveToSuperview:` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282288/is-willmovetosuperview-called-with-nil-when-removing-a-view-from-a-hierarchy).

Comment: overriding dealloc to send a notification should work... but hopefully someone else has a better idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "move out"? Scroll out of view, or removing the cell completely?

Comment: Dequeuing means "take out of the queue and put on screen". Queuing means "remove from screen and put in the queue", so you really mean "queuing"?

Comment: you're right, I corrected the question

Comment: In that case you're going to have to monitor scroll events and then check for the visible rect whenever it changes. Note that recent versions of iOS and OS X will render scroll view contents that is *not currently visible* in order to improve scrolling performance (basically the pixels are already rendered and in the GPU when the user starts scrolling). Make sure your code is fast... perhaps offload it to a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

On the delegation method of `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: this method called after scrolling out, not before

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolling out"?

Comment: When the cell is no longer visible. Povillas want's when that it's about to happen.